# "like" queries in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, wildcard

How do I get wildcard text searches (like SQL's "like" statement) in ASP.net MVC using the edo entity framework?

I assumed this would work:

```
var elig = (from e in _documentDataModel.Protocol_Eligibility_View
            where e.criteria.Contains(query)
            select e);
```

But it returns no results even when searching for a query string that's definitely in the database. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12):

This guy made a very nice "WhereLike" extension for Linq that accepts any wildcard character and compares two values (one of which comes from an expression) with a generic method derived from the location of the wildcard.

- x%  -> startswith
- %x  -> endswith
- %x% -> contains

http://trentacular.com/2010/08/linq-to-entities-wild-card-like-extension-method/

EDIT:
The article seems to be down. I will paste the extention code below:

```
public static class LinqHelper
    {
        //Support IQueryable (Linq to Entities)
        public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereLike<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, string>> valueSelector, string value, char wildcard)
        {
            return source.Where(BuildLikeExpression(valueSelector, value, wildcard));
        }

        //Support IEnumerable (Linq to objects)
        public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereLike<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> sequence, Func<TSource, string> expression, string value, char wildcard)
        {
            var regEx = WildcardToRegex(value, wildcard);

            //Prevent multiple enumeration:
            var arraySequence = sequence as TSource[] ?? sequence.ToArray();

            try
            {
                return arraySequence.Where(item => Regex.IsMatch(expression(item), regEx));
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException)
            {
                return arraySequence;
            }
        }

        //Used for the IEnumerable support
        private static string WildcardToRegex(string value, char wildcard)
        {
            return "(?i:^" + Regex.Escape(value).Replace("\\" + wildcard, "." + wildcard) + "$)";
        }

        //Used for the IQueryable support
        private static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> BuildLikeExpression<TElement>(Expression<Func<TElement, string>> valueSelector, string value, char wildcard)
        {
            if (valueSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector");

            var method = GetLikeMethod(value, wildcard);

            value = value.Trim(wildcard);
            var body = Expression.Call(valueSelector.Body, method, Expression.Constant(value));

            var parameter = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, parameter);
        }

        private static MethodInfo GetLikeMethod(string value, char wildcard)
        {
            var methodName = "Equals";

            var textLength = value.Length;
            value = value.TrimEnd(wildcard);
            if (textLength > value.Length)
            {
                methodName = "StartsWith";
                textLength = value.Length;
            }

            value = value.TrimStart(wildcard);
            if (textLength > value.Length)
            {
                methodName = (methodName == "StartsWith") ? "Contains" : "EndsWith";
            }

            var stringType = typeof(string);
            return stringType.GetMethod(methodName, new[] { stringType });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this link provided in the answer is dead. Thank you for providing with the code.

Comment: how to use the extension method?

Comment: On any of your IQueryable or IEnumerable you invoke it, like so: IQueryableVar.WhereLike(item => item.property, textbox.Text, '*'); where textbox.Text is an example on what you would like the property to be like.

Comment: Thank you Jon, what does the third parameter '*' is doing?

Comment: As you can see it's passed all the way down to the method "GetLikeMethod" where it is used to determine wether to use StartsWith, EndsWith or Contains. So if your value would be "bla* ", which could mean you need everything starting with "bla", you pass the * char along with the wildcard parameter and expect the method to return "Startswith("bla")".

Answer (score 12):

#### 2019 update

For Entity Framework 6.2 you can use [DBFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

For example:

```
try
{
    using (var db = new YOUREntities())
    {
        var data = db.LenderProgram.Where(i => DbFunctions.Like(i.LenderProgramCode, "OTO%"))
            .ToList();
        return data;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.HandleException();
}
```

Comment: If someone stumbles on this, I had to use `EF.Functions.Like(...,...)` instead of `DbFunctions.Like(...,...)` with EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.14

Answer (score 6):

String.Contains should work appropriately.  SQL's LIKE statement is typically handled via String.StartsWith, String.Contains, or String.EndsWith.

However, it is possible you're having casing issues.  You could try:

```
var elig = (from e in _documentDataModel.Protocol_Eligibility_View
        where e.criteria.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower())
        select e);
```

Comment: Upon looking at my issue more closely, it looks like my issue is somewhere else, not in the .contains statement.

Answer (score 5):

Linq to entities does not support the SqlMethods method, but you could use the string functions instead:

```
.Where(entity => entity.Name.Contains("xyz"))

.Where(entity => entity.Name.EndsWith("xyz"))

.Where(entity => entity.Name.StartsWith("xyz"))
```

Answer (score 3):

The System.Data.Linq.SqlClient namespace contains the SqlMethods class. You can use it's Like method like this:

```
var elig = from e in _documentDataModel.Protocol_Eligibility_View
           where SqlMethods.Like(e.criteria, query)
           select e;
```

Answer (score 2):

I started using the code that Jon Koeter posted from the blog post in another answer that no longer appears to exist.

However, I found it didn't really work properly, especially when using an `IEnumerable`. Namely, it was resolving the enumerable using `ToArray` and using a regex to match, rather than the built in functions.

Since I only want to resolve my `IEnumerable` once I have finished filtering, I made some changes to convert to an `IQueryable` then use the rest of the code to find the correct Entity Framework method and call that. This way, the query itself is not called against the database until later, and it avoids the use of a regex.

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereLike<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, string>> valueSelector, string value, char wildcard)
{
    return source.Where(BuildLikeExpression(valueSelector, value, wildcard));
}

public static IEnumerable<T> WhereLike<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, string>> valueSelector, string value, char wildcard)
{
    return source.AsQueryable().WhereLike(valueSelector, value, wildcard);
}

private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildLikeExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> valueSelector, string value, char wildcard)
{
    if (valueSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector");

    var method = GetLikeMethod(value, wildcard);
    value = value.Trim(wildcard);
    var body = Expression.Call(valueSelector.Body, method, Expression.Constant(value));
    var parameter = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
}

private static MethodInfo GetLikeMethod(string value, char wildcard)
{
    var methodName = "Equals";

    var textLength = value.Length;
    value = value.TrimEnd(wildcard);
    if (textLength > value.Length)
    {
        methodName = "StartsWith";
        textLength = value.Length;
    }

    value = value.TrimStart(wildcard);
    if (textLength > value.Length)
    {
        methodName = (methodName == "StartsWith") ? "Contains" : "EndsWith";
    }

    var stringType = typeof(string);
    return stringType.GetMethod(methodName, new[] { stringType });
}
```

Usage:

```
// example data set
var data = new List<Person> {
    new Person{FirstName="John", LastName="Smith"}, 
    new Person{FirstName="Jane", LastName="Doe"}
};

data.WhereLike(x=>x.FirstName, "John", "%"); // returns John Smith
data.WhereLike(x=>x.FirstName, "J%", "%"); // returns John Smith and Jane Smith
```

Comment: I have to say, the article only had code for the IQueryable, and I think it works wonders. I added the IEnumerable code myself (might have taken that from another website, don't remember) and figured I might as well share it with you guys.