# LIKE with Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-entities

I know the `.Contains()` method does like `LIKE %therm%`, the `.StartsWith()` method does like `LIKE therm%` and the `.EndsWith()` method like `LIKE %therm` but...

Is there a way to do like below on `**Linq to Entities**`?

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Users] WHERE Name LIKE 'rodrigo%otavio%diniz%waltenberg'
```

PS: I'M USING LINQ TO ENTITIES. NOT LINQ TO SQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SQL 'LIKE' with LINQ to Entities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095781/how-to-use-sql-like-with-linq-to-entities)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [you can do this with ESQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399359.aspx)/Query Builder syntax:

```
var matching = Context.Users.Where("it.Name LIKE 'rodrigo%otavio%diniz%waltenberg'");
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
from u in context.users
    where System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.Like(
        u.Name, 
        "rodrigo%otavio%diniz%waltenberg")
    select u
```

**Edit:**
It turns out this only works with LINQ2SQL, not LINQ2Entities.
[Linq SqlMethods.Like fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584598/linq-sqlmethods-like-fails) suggests that you can use `Where` directly on the table.

Comment: Exception: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @Rodrigo: Hmmm, l2e works to close to l2s to be confusing... I updated my answer with a linq to another question that might be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

How about using regular expressions with your LINQ statement? Something like the following:

```
        RegularExpressions.Regex p 
             = new RegularExpressions.Regex("rodrigo%otavio%diniz%waltenberg");

        using (DataContext.MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext())
        {
            var result = from u in context.users
                      where p.IsMatch(u.name)
                      select u;
        }
```

Comment: Exception: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsMatch(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.