# How can I build logic upon supplied logic in a LINQ-to-Entities Where expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression-trees

I often come across, in LINQ for Entity Framework, a pattern where I add a `.Where` clause if a string value is specified, like:

```
IQueryable<Foo> query = Foos.AsQueryable()
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(nameFilter)) query = query.Where(x => x.Name == name);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(addressFilter) != null) query = query.Where(x => x.Address == addressFilter );
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(cityFilter) != null) query = query.Where(x => x.City == cityFilter );
// ...
```

I wanted to clean this up and avoid repeating the filter.  I thought I could create an extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereEqualIfSpecified<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query,
    Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldDelegate,
    string filterValue)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterValue) 
        ? query 
        : query.Where(x => fieldDelegate(x) == filterValue);  // not valid, see question below
}
```

So that I can instead change my code to:

```
IQueryable<Foo> query = Foos.AsQueryable()
    .WhereEqualIfSpecified(x => x.Name, nameFilter)
    .WhereEqualIfSpecified(x => x.Address, addressFilter)
    .WhereEqualIfSpecified(x => x.City, cityFilter)
    // ...
;
```

But I found that, in the `WhereEqualIfSpecified` method above, `fieldDelegate` must be compiled to a `Func()` to be invoked against the entity source, which ruins the point of doing these steps, which would be executed in the database in my original code.

I am missing the last step of how to create a new `Expression` from `fieldDelegate` that can do a comparison, rather than just returning the string value.  Will this approach work?  How do I make the necessary `Expression` in `WhereEqualIfSpecified` to allow LINQ-to-Entities to execute it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is to compose expressions.  Expressions, unlike delegates, are a bit tricker to compose.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37602870/1159478) is one implementation of how to compose expressions.  Once you have that `Compose` method you can write your extension method as:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereEqualIfSpecified<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query,
    Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpression,
    string filterValue)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterValue) 
        ? query 
        : query.Where(fieldExpression.Compose(value => value == filterValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  It worked, and I learned a lot about working with expressions.