# ASP MVC best method to search/return all values from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the case of a default value being used in an ASP MVC drown down list, I need the code to return all values or simply ignore that particular search criteria.

Below is the code I have in my View and Controller. Since the '%' does not seem to be working, is there another keyword/operator that will do the job?

View:

```
        <form method="post">
          <select name="Table" title="Table" style="font-size:8pt;">
            <option value="%">--Table Name--</option>
            <option value="AgentContEd">CE</option>
            <option value="AgentProductTraining">PT</option>
          </select>
          <select name="IssueType" style="font-size:8pt;">
            <option value="%">--Issue Type--</option>
            <option value="W">Warning</option>
            <option value="E">Error</option>
          </select>
          <select name="Status" style="font-size:8pt;">
            <option value="%">--Status Type--</option>
            <option value="O">Open</option>
            <option value="U">Under Review</option>
          </select>


        <input type="image" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Filter.bmp")" alt="Filter" style="padding-top: 0px;" />
        <a href="#" style="padding-left: 30px;"></a>
        </form>
```

Controller:

```
    public ViewResult Index(FormCollection dropDownSelection)
    {
        //security
        //if (!Security.IsViewer(User)) return RedirectToAction("Message", "Home", new { id = 2 });

        //if (ViewBag.Level == 0) return RedirectToAction("Message", "Home", new { id = 2 });

        string table = dropDownSelection["Table"];
        string issue = dropDownSelection["IssueType"];
        string status = dropDownSelection["Status"];

        var followUpItem = from follow in db.FollowUpItems
                           where follow.TableName.Equals(table) &&
                                 follow.IssueType.Equals(issue) &&
                                 follow.Status.Equals(status)
                           select follow;

        return View(followUpItem.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: *cough* [`Sqlmethods.Like`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx) *cough*

Comment: We are using .Net 4.0. Is SqlMethods.Like only available in 4.5?

Comment: supported in [3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and up.

Comment: Ugh... this threw a "NotSupportedException" even though we are connecting to a SQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't compiled this, but I'm guessing you want something like:

```
 public ViewResult Index(FormCollection dropDownSelection)
    {
        //security
        //if (!Security.IsViewer(User)) return RedirectToAction("Message", "Home", new { id = 2 });

        //if (ViewBag.Level == 0) return RedirectToAction("Message", "Home", new { id = 2 });

        string table = dropDownSelection["Table"];
        string issue = dropDownSelection["IssueType"];
        string status = dropDownSelection["Status"];

        var followUpItem = from follow in db.FollowUpItems
                   where (follow.TableName.Equals(table) || table.Equals("%")) &&
                         (follow.IssueType.Equals(issue) || issue.Equals("%")) &&
                         (follow.Status.Equals(status) || status.Equals("%"))
                   select follow;

        return View(followUpItem.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: This is basically what we're trying to do. However, we have the default value of the drop down list set to '%' so we don't have to worry about it in the controller if no value is selected by the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either [`SqlMethods.Like`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx) or simply the [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method. (Keep in mind that `String.Contains` will be problematic if you retain the use of `%` or any other SQL wildcards.)

So, the three variations would look like:

```
var followUpItem = from follow in db.FollowUpItems
                   where SqlMethods.Like(follow.TableName, table) &&
                         follow.IssueType.Contains(issue) &&
                         follow.Status.Equals(status)
                   select follow;
```

Comment: We are using .Net 4.0. Is SqlMethods.Like only available in 4.5?

Comment: @NealR: Yes, just look at the "Other versions" drop down on that linked MSDN page.

Comment: Ugh... this threw a "NotSupportedException" even though we are connecting to a SQL database.

Comment: You only need to comment on this answer if it's relevant to what I've posted (and not the question). That being said, are you using LINQ-to-SQL or just the LINQ library?

Comment: If you're using LINQ-to-Entities, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2585564/298053).

Comment: We are using LINQ only the LINQ Library i believe.