# Dynamic Linq to add LIKE to where clause

Tags: linq, entity-framework, dynamic-linq

I'm trying to perform a LIKE clause in an entity query. The [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095781/how-to-use-sql-like-with-linq-to-entities) I've seen use dynamic linq to do this kind of thing, but my code...

```
var query = context.StudySet
    .Where("it.PatientName LIKE @patientName", new ObjectParameter("patientName", patientName);
```

...gives me a System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException with

```
Additional information: Expression of type 'Boolean' expected
```

*context* is a DbContext from EF 6 code-first, *patientName* is a string

Please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Wouldn't something like `var query = context.StudySet.Where((it) => it.PatientName.Contains(patientName))` work for you, without using Dynamic LINQ?

Comment: The value for patientName will come from a search box which will take wildcards. I guess I can split the string and build up a query combining StartsWith, Contains, EndsWith etc. I just saw LIKE as being a bit less code.

Comment: That makes sense, splitting it doesn't sound like fun!  Maybe [`SqlMethods.Like`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx) would work, like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3913727/2278086)?  Just not sure it it works with EF.

Comment: No that's right, it doesn't work, it's Linq to SQL only unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry - I guess I'm going down the path you have already travelled!  How about using `SqlQuery` and raw SQL, something like `var query = context.StudySet.SqlQuery("select * from StudySet where PatientName LIKE @patientName", new SqlParameter("@patientName", patientName));`?

Comment: Yeah that'd work. Thanks Mark.

Comment: Have you tried `var query = context.StudySet.Where(s => s.PatientName.Contains(userInput))` -- I realize this is not Dynamic Linq, but if you are hard coding your table name in a string, this would be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've realised my mistake.

I had assumed the method to pass the query was part of Dynamic Linq but actually it's just a variant of the standard Where method on ObjectQuery. If I get the ObjectContext from my (code first) DbContext it's all good.

```
ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
ObjectSet<Study> studySet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<Study>();

var query = studySet.
    Where("it.PatientName LIKE @patientName", new ObjectParameter("patientName", patientName));
```

Comment: This is powerful and flexible. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

if you want use DynamicLINQ you need change your code like this

```
var query = context.StudySet.Where("it.PatientName.Contains(@0)", patientName);
```

because DynamicLinq can't parse `LIKE` operator

Comment: LIKE should be [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399359(v=vs.100).aspx). I don't have to use Dynamic Linq, I want to do a LIKE. Contains != LIKE (see above).

Comment: @nopskazoid eSQL not the same DynamicLINQ :-) possibly you need change tags for question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to use like with a LINQ query, but you could use a raw SQL query:

```
var query = context.StudySet.SqlQuery(
    "select * from StudySet where PatientName LIKE @patientName",
    new SqlParameter("@patientName", patientName));
```