# Advance search in LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

How can i search in LINQ as stated below??
I Want to enter a string like this "a%b%c%d%" in my textbox and want result as we get in SQL.

```
Select * 
from TableName 
Where ColumnName Like 'a%b%c%d%'
```

Comment: Linq-To-Sql or Linq-To-Entities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do SQL Like % in Linq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835790/how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq)

Comment: @TimBourguignon: although the acepted answer doesn't help. But an answer on this question depends on the architecture, in Linq-To-Sql you could use `SqlMethods.Like`. I don't know how it works in LInq-To-Entities. I guess you need [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3095963/284240).

Comment: I also use Like operater but it could'nt work.

Comment: @Roberto it's a valid SQL Query. You can check it.

Comment: @TalmeezHussain: you also use `LIKE` operator? How do you use it, there is no `LIKE` operator unless you don't use `VB.NET`(which works differently and has nothing to do with LINQ). Show your LINQ query. You also still haven't answered the question whether you use Linq-To-Sql or Linq-To-Entities.

Comment: var myvar = from q in query where SqlMethods.Like(q.UserName, firstname) select q;
where firstname = "a%b%c%d%"

Answer (score 0):

LINQ doesn't have like operator, so you could first check if it contains a, b, c and d, then check if a is at start, b is before c, and c before d. Like this:

```
from item in context.TableName
where item.ColumnName.StartsWith("a") && item.ColumnName.IndexOf("b") != -1
&& item.ColumnName.IndexOf("c") != -1 && item.ColumnName.IndexOf("d") != -1
&& (
    item.ColumnName.IndexOf("b") < item.ColumnName.IndexOf("c")
    && item.ColumnName.IndexOf("c") < item.ColumnName.IndexOf("d")
   )   
select item;
```

Comment: Thanks @Roberto.
How we can make it generic??

Answer (score -1):

```
FROM item in context.TableName
WHERE item.ColumnName.StartWith("a%") 
   OR item.ColumnName.StartWith("b%") 
   OR item.ColumnName.StartWith("c%") 
   OR item.ColumnName.StartWith("d%")   
SELECT item;
```

Comment: That's not the same as OP's sql. You check if it starts with a or b or c or d. OP wants only rows where the column starts with a, then arbitrary, then b, then arbitrary, then c, then arbitrary, then d, then arbitrary.