# How to make LINQ execute a (SQL) LIKE range search

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am in big need of help, i have been trying to do this for some time now.

So I have this Query:

```
Select name from BlaBlaBla

order by 

case when name like '9%' then 1 end,
case when name like '8%' then 1 end,
case when name like '7%' then 1 end,
case when name like '6%' then 1 end,
case when name like '5%' then 1 end,
case when name like '4%' then 1 end,
case when name like '3%' then 1 end,
case when name like '2%' then 1 end,
case when name like '1%' then 1 end,
case when name like '0%' then 1 end,

name
```

And I want to implement it in a new C#, Asp.Net, class, in my Solution, to the Domain Project, so it will be an OrderType Filter, for some function...

for now I have this:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");

var paramName = Expression.Property(param, "Name");
var regexMatch = Expression.Constant("^[0-9]");
var startsWithDigit = Expression.Call(typeof(Regex), "IsMatch", 
                                             null, paramName);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(startsWithDigit, 
                                              param);

return namesList.OrderBy(lambda)
           .ThenBy(BlaBla1())
           .ThenByDescending(BlaBla2())
           .ThenByDescending(BlaBla3())
           .ThenBy(BlaBla4());
```

But it tells me, that Expression does not contain "IsMatch" method.

Can you please help me?
Thank you!!!

Comment: It looks like you are working with some LINQ-supporting ORM. which one is it? Also, why are you constructing the expression manually instead of using LINQ syntax?

Comment: Do you want this ordering to be executed in the database using some ORM or in memory ?

Comment: Well, the ORM used here, is Linq to Sql

Comment: The thing is: I have a list of Names, and some of them starts with digits, I want to filter them (the ones that startwith digit) at the end of  the list ordered from 0 to 9... And I want all of these to happen within Linq, ORM used ENTITY or ADO (Does not matter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that expressions containing `Regex` can't be translated to SQL, so even when you'd succeed in building a correct expression, you can't use it in LINQ to a SQL backend. However, SQL's `LIKE` method also supports range wildcards like `[0-9]`, so the trick is to make your LINQ translate to SQL containing a `LIKE` statement.

LINQ-to-SQL offers the possibility to use the SQL `LIKE` statement *explicitly*:

```
return namesList.OrderBy(r => SqlMethods.Like(r.Name, "[0-9]%")) ...
```

This [SqlMethods](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods?view=netframework-4.7.1) class can only be used in LINQ-to-SQL though. In Entity Framework there are string functions that translate to `LIKE` *implicitly*, but none of them enable the range wildcard (`[x-y]`). In EF a statement like ...

```
return namesList.OrderBy(r => r.Name.StartsWith("[0-9]")) ...
```

... would translate to nonsense:

```
[Name] LIKE '~[0-9]%' ESCAPE '~'
```

I.e. it vainly looks for names starting with the literal string "[0-9]". So as long as you keep using LINQ-to-SQL `SqlMethods.Like` is the way to go.

In Entity Framework 6.1.3 (and lower) we have to use a slightly different way to obtain the same result ...

```
return namesList.OrderBy(r => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("[0-9]%", c.Name) == 1) ...
```

... because `PatIndex` in [SqlFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.patindex.aspx) also supports range pattern matching.

But in Entity Framwork 6.2 we're back on track with LINQ-to-SQL because of the new `DbFunctions.Like` function:

```
return namesList.OrderBy(r => DbFunctions.Like(r.Name, "[0-9]%")) ...
```

Finally, also Entity Framework core has a `Like` function:

```
return namesList.OrderBy(r => EF.Functions.Like(r.Name, "[0-9]%")) ...
```

Comment: Thank you @Gert. This really helped me solve my problem, and it is working now

Comment: Thanks for good and complete answer. Details like ef version help me a lot.

Comment: with EF 6.4.4 use SqlMethods.Like   ->   LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)'

Comment: @Omid-RH *This SqlMethods class can only be used in LINQ-to-SQL*.

Comment: Thanks @Gert-Arnold

Answer (score 0):

Below you see a sample for this kind of way to handle cases for your orderings.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Obvious> list = new List<Obvious>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new Obvious(i.ToString(), i));
        }

        string name = list[30].name;
        switch (name)
        {
            case "9":
                list.OrderBy(o => o.perc)
                    .ThenByDescending(o => o.name);
                break;
            default:
                list.OrderByDescending(o => o.name)
                    .ThenBy(o => o.perc);
                break;
        }
    }

    public class Obvious
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int perc { get; set; }
        public Obvious(string _name, int _perc)
        {
            this.name = _name;
            this.perc = _perc;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. He wants to build an expression he can send to an ORM which supports LINQ. Or at least, so it seems.

Comment: Hello. Sorry for answering this late. Yes that is exactelly what I want! Because, that is exactelly how the others are made. And I want that Names starting with a digit to be at the end of the list, ordered asc

Comment: And yes the ORM, is LINQ

Comment: Which is the thing "you exactly want" ? My solution or the one which @TsahiAsher suggested ?

Comment: Well, @Gert, just answered my problem for me, and I almost finished my syntax(algorithm). Thank you @Kadir!

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I wouldn't try using Expressions to solve this issue since it brings in a lot of complexity.

I see that you would like to have a generic method, so it can work with different domain entities, yet you are expecting that each entity has a `Name` property. 
You can solve this in a more simple way by defining interface that contains `Name` property. Like this:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var test = new List<YourDomainEntity>()
        {
            new YourDomainEntity() { Name = "1test", OtherProperty = "1"},
            new YourDomainEntity() { Name = "2test",  OtherProperty = "2" },
            new YourDomainEntity() { Name = "2test", OtherProperty = "1"   }
        };

        var k = Foo(test).ToList();
    }

    public interface INameOrderable
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IOtherPropertyOrderable
    {
        string OtherProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> list) where T : INameOrderable, IOtherPropertyOrderable
    {
        return list.OrderBy(a => a.Name, new NamesDescComparer()).ThenBy(b => b.OtherProperty);
    }

    public class NamesDescComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y) => -String.CompareOrdinal(x, y);
    }

    class YourDomainEntity : INameOrderable, IOtherPropertyOrderable
    {
        public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I believe the method `Foo` is what you are looking for.

Note the `where T : INameOrderable` part. It restricts usage of this method to entities that implement `INameOrderable` interface