# LINQ Query to search for users with partial name

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    employeeTable
WHERE 
    (
    concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) like concat('%', replace(@MatchString, ' ', '%'), '%')
        or
    concat(last_name, ' ', first_name) like concat('%', replace(@MatchString, ' ', '%'), '%')
    )
```

It works perfectly by searching both name and last name with partial values., by searching users with partial strings. So for example:

"ric jon" will find Rick Jones, Richard Jonesy, and Jonathan Prichter.

I have the following Linq Query, using Entity Framework:

```
from employee in context.Employee
                    where employee.first_name.Contains(matchString)
                    || employee.last_name.Contains(matchString)
                    select employee
```

But the string "ric jon" does not find anything.

I can't seem to make that linq query work the same as the SQL query.

Comment: `where (employee.first_name + " " + employee.last_name).Contains(matchString)` (and the reverse)?

Comment: Same problem. It matches the first name partially as expected, but when putting a space in the string it stops finding altogether.

Comment: Use a [Like function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46975884/861716) if you can.

Answer (score 0):

That SQL wouldn't in fact find those records you sampled with the given "ric jon". What you are asking for is a special filter which IMHO requires a function that is not natively supported by the backend (you didn't specify your backend but anyway at least I don't know a backend that would support this natively). Something like this would work (note that you are getting the Employee records to local, this is not done at backend level):

```
Func<Employee, string[], bool> match = (emp, _parts) => {
     return 
     ((emp.FirstName.IndexOf(_parts[0],StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase  ) != -1) &&
     (_parts.Length == 1 || emp.LastName.IndexOf(_parts[1], StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)) ||
     ((_parts.Length == 1 || emp.FirstName.IndexOf(_parts[1], StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1) &&
     (emp.LastName.IndexOf(_parts[0], StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1));
};

string search = "ric jon";
var result = context.Employee.AsEnumerable()
              .Where(n => match(n, search.Split()));
```

Update:

You can use this one which would be supported by many backends:

```
string search = "ric jon";
string[] parts = search.ToLowerInvariant().Split();
string p1 = parts.Length < 1 ? "" :parts[0];
string p2 = parts.Length < 2 ? "" :parts[1];

var result = context.Employee.Where(n => 
    ((n.FirstName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(p1) &&
     n.LastName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(p2))) ||
     ((n.FirstName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(p2) &&
     n.LastName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(p1))));
```

Comment: Pulling in all records to filter on the client side, and limiting the search terms to two words is not a good solution.

Comment: @CodeCaster, 2 words search terms is OP's idea, not mine. I also supplied code that doesn't require to get the records client side. It is the second piece of code that you missed I think.