# why the contains statement generates strange characters in sql using EF 6

Tags: entity-framework, character, contains, diacritics

I had a problem with the accented word search and solved it in sql server by encapsulating the vowels with the symbols [], to find records with and without accents. For example, WHERE Name LIKE '% [aa] ci [oo] n%', this works well in the SQL server, but when generating the query with EF using the operator Contains this generates a very strange SQL record, and At the moment of executing the query, it seems that the server modifies the search concept by prefixing the characters "~"

I have tried use the statement Contains (concept), the Contains statement generates LIKE in sql but it modifies the string when it includes the symbols [], including in between this symbol "~"

input:

string concept = "[aá]cc[ií][oó]n" //-> that works in sql server query

EF Query:

```
 using (Entities ctx = new Entities())
 {
    ctx.Database.Log = Console.Write;
    var result = ctx.Product.Where(w =w.Name.Contains(concept)).ToList();
    return result;
 }
```

The sql generated:

```
SELECT
   [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
   [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],
   [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description],
   [Extent1].[Price] AS [Price]
  FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Name] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE '~'
```

-- p__linq__0: '%~[aá]cc~[ií]~[oó]n%' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 8000)

the "~[aá]cc~[ií]~[oó]n" is different to the "[aá]cc[ií][oó]n" from EF
in EF the input is string, and when sql is executed the input is AnsiString and set stranger characters

Comment: `Contains` isn't implemented as supporting all possible pattern matching wildcards. Use [DbFunctions.Like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46975884/861716).

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server uses the square brackets as part of their wildcard expression searching, so if you want to search on them as a string they need to be escaped. While using `.Contains()` will result in a LIKE query, EF is treating the expression as a literal for "%value%" so it will escape any brackets or wildcard characters.

EF is escaping them with the Tilde, so it registers Tilde as the escape character in the generated script.

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/like.php

Since you want to use the [] for the wildcard like operation, you need to use `DbFunctions.Like` with your bracketed expression.

```
var result = ctx.Product.Where(w=> DbFunctions.Like(w.Name, concept)).ToList();
```