# Wildcard (*,!) on search using Regex

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search, wildcard

I'm new in MVC, I want to perform Wildcard (*, !) search on database. This is what I have done by using Regex:

Controller:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;


namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        CrossWord_dbEntities db = new CrossWord_dbEntities();

        public ActionResult Index(string searching)
        {
            var regEx = WildcardToRegex(searching);
            return View(db.tbl_values.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.Name, regEx, RegexOptions.Singleline)));//.ToList()));
        }

public static string WildcardToRegex(string pattern)
        {
            return "^" + Regex.Escape(pattern).
            Replace("\\*", ".*").
            Replace("\\?", ".") + "$";
        }

    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.tbl_values>

<br /><br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
@Html.TextBox("searching") <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Results</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model.Count() == 0)
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="color:red">
                    No Result 
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.Name
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }

    </tbody>

</table>
```

With the above code when i run i get an exception in line: "@if (Model.Count() == 0)"

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsMatch(System.String, System.String, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

what i have to do to fix this problem?

i tried to write in the return line of the controller adding "ToList()"

```
return View(db.tbl_values.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.Name, regEx, RegexOptions.Singleline).ToList()));
```

but i get the same expction on this line.

thanks Amir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is straightforward: `Regex.IsMatch()` method has no equivalent SQL statement when executing query in LINQ to Entities mode. You need to put `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` method before `Where` clause to materialize `DbContext` entity into `IEnumerable` object:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    CrossWord_dbEntities db = new CrossWord_dbEntities();

    public ActionResult Index(string searching)
    {
        var regEx = WildcardToRegex(searching);
        return View(db.tbl_values.AsEnumerable().Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.Name, regEx, RegexOptions.Singleline)));
    }
}
```

Since you have `WildcardToRegex` method which only works in `IEnumerable` or LINQ to Objects, you can try adding other methods as described in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29298128/6378815) for use with `IQueryable` entities as follows:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereLike<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, string>> valueSelector, string value, char wildcard)
{
    return source.Where(BuildLikeExpression(valueSelector, value, wildcard));
}

private static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> BuildLikeExpression<TElement>(Expression<Func<TElement, string>> valueSelector, string value, char wildcard)
{
    if (valueSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector");

    var method = GetLikeMethod(value, wildcard);

    value = value.Trim(wildcard);
    var body = Expression.Call(valueSelector.Body, method, Expression.Constant(value));

    var parameter = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, parameter);
}

private static MethodInfo GetLikeMethod(string value, char wildcard)
{
    var methodName = "Equals";

    var textLength = value.Length;
    value = value.TrimEnd(wildcard);
    if (textLength > value.Length)
    {
        methodName = "StartsWith";
        textLength = value.Length;
    }

    value = value.TrimStart(wildcard);
    if (textLength > value.Length)
    {
        methodName = (methodName == "StartsWith") ? "Contains" : "EndsWith";
    }

    var stringType = typeof(string);
    return stringType.GetMethod(methodName, new[] { stringType });
}
```

Then use `WhereLike` method for any entities implementing `IQueryable` like example below:

```
// usage example
using (CrossWord_dbEntities db = new CrossWord_dbEntities())
{
    var query = db.tbl_values.WhereLike(x => x.Name, "[search text]", "[wildcard character]");
}
```

Similar issue:

[linq to entities doesn't recognize a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845993/linq-to-entities-doesnt-recognize-a-method)